# SwiftUI fill a View inside a switch

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, geometryreader

Does anyone know a correct way to do the following:

I have a view which produces a path and I want to fill it either with a color or with a gradient (which are different types).

For this, I have a enum which I pass to the view from the parent view:

```swift
enum FillColor {
  case color(_ color: Color)
  case gradient(color1: Color, color2: Color)
}
```

Inside a view, I have a path:

```
 var body: some View {
   GeometryReader { geometry in
     Path { path in
     ...
     }
   }   
}
```

I then need to switch and do smth like:

```
switch color {
  case .color(let c):
    path.fill(c)
  case .gradient(let c1, let c2):
    let gradient = ...
    path.fill(gradient)
}
```

Do I create a variable for a `Path`?
But I need to use `GeometryReader` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did is I encapsulated creating a path into a function and then used it to avoid code repetition.
I pass path as **inout** parameter in order to be able to mutate it.
Sure it's not the ideal solution though..

```swift
GeometryReader { geometry in
  switch color {
  case .color(let c):
    Path { path in createPath(&path, geometry: geometry) }
    .fill(c)
  case .gradient(let c1, let c2):
    let gradient = LinearGradient(...)
    Path { path in createPath(&path, geometry: geometry) }
    .fill(gradient)
  }
}
```